# Getting input inside a loop using Java

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to use `scanner.nextLine()` inside a loop, but I get an exception.
The problem is located in this part of the code.

```
        while(!sentence.equals("quit")){
        dealWithSentence(sentence, voc);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence:");
        sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

There is the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
>       at il.ac.tau.cs.sw1.ex4.SpellingCorrector.main(SpellingCorrector.java:34)

That's my full method code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filePath = scanner.nextLine();
    if (filePath.contains(" ")){
        scanner.close();
        throw new Exception("[ERROR] the file path isnt correct");
    }

    File file = new File(filePath);
    String[] voc = scanVocabulary(new Scanner(file));
    if (voc == null)
    {
        scanner.close();
        throw new Exception("[ERROR] the file isnt working");

    }


    System.out.println("Read " + voc.length + " words from " + file.getName());

    System.out.println("Enter your sentence:");

    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();

    while(!sentence.equals("quit")){
        dealWithSentence(sentence, voc);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence:");
        sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

Scanner.nextLine() works as follows..

```
   String s = "Hello World! \n 3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";

   // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

   // print the next line
   System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

   // print the next line again
   System.out.println("" + scanner.nextLine());

   // close the scanner
   scanner.close();
   }
```

this will give you the  following output

```
Hello World!
3 + 3.0 = 6.0 true
```

So basically it starts scanning and skips until the first new line character, and then it returns whatever it has skipped so far as the output. In your case if you have only a single sentence and no new line (\n) in it at all, it will skip the entire length and never find a new line. thereby throwing the exception... add a new line character in mid of sentence and see if the exception goes away

Credits go to : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm

Answer (score 2):

Check `scanner.hasNextLine()` before you use `scanner.nextLine()`:

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  sentence = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Otherwise, the scanner might not have any element and cannot provide a *next line*.

Usually, you will read your input in a loop, such as:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.println("Line: " + scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Op, This is better. Use this.

Comment: but the problem is there is no next line, I want to get it as an input from the user

Comment: You'll have to loop over the input steam then and each time a line is terminated, the ``Scanner`` will return a ``nextLine()``.

Comment: you mean each loop needs to contain Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);? because I've tried it but it doesnt work as well

Comment: No, just create one ``Scanner`` instance and make it read user input in a loop. To prevent the ``NoSuchElementException``, check your scanner with ``hasNext()`` before calling ``nextLine()``.